# SSMS & Firebird : Cannot Connect to Existing .GDB Database

Tags: ssms, firebird, firebird2.5

I am trying to create a linked server in SSMS that connects to an existing .GDB database. I have tried:

1. Creating a linked server in SSMS with the provider string / password
2. Creating an ODBC connection with the Firebird ODBC driver
3. Connecting with Firebird's command tool (GSEC)

All 3 of these methods have returned the error : "User name and password are not defined." I know that the username and password are correct because I can use them to log on to the application connected to the database. It seems to me that there is some kind of Firebird configuration I may need to do so I can pass the username and password over to the database.

I have had issues in the past where I couldn't access the database and needed Firebird's GDS32.dll file, but I have done this and it still throws the authentication error. I am on a Windows 2008 R2 Server (64 bit), SSMS 2008 R2, and Firebird 2.5. I would appreciate any and all of your help.

Thanks!

Comment: The username and password of an application are not necessarily the same as the database credentials used by the application.

Comment: You are right in that, but from what we have been told they are the same. (The program is Management Plus, an EMR program).

Comment: Firebird stores user accounts/passwords apart from the database file. So, if you moved your database to a new server you need somehow to recreate user accounts.